# How to prevent notifications from grabbing focus in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, notification, focus

I updated from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 last year, and the Gnome notifications are a nuisance.  In 16.04 with Unity, notifications would not grab focus, they'd just appear as an overlay in the corner -- you couldn't even click on them.  In 18.04 with Gnome, when a notification pops up, it grabs focus from the current window.  This is really disruptive, since I routinely have to monitor multiple chat channels that send notifications to me.  I'll be in the middle of typing something in one channel when a notification from another interrupts, causing me to type several letters into the void before I manually get the cursor back where it's supposed to be, completely breaking my flow.

I definitely need to be aware of the notifications as they come in, so I can't just block, mute, or hide them, but I don't want them to interrupt what I'm doing when they appear. Is there a way to do this that I'm overlooking?  I'd prefer a built-in/official solution over one that requires installing a patch or mod, if possible.

Comment: Lookup "focus stealing prevention".

Comment: There is an gitlab gnome issue, but the proposed fix does not work: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/338

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes a notification popup can take focus
sometimes only
This is because of the **smart focus** feature of the Gnome [Window Manager](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html)


A workaround will be to change the **smart** focus default feature to **strict**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-new-windows 'strict'
```

Comment: This is the same fix as in https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/338. There are still notifications which break the focus

Comment: Not really the same. Please specify which notifications are affected by your statement

Comment: This did solve the issue for me, as far as I can tell.

Comment: This seems to have worked!  Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to restart something after applying these settings? Google Calendar can still override this setup and takeover.

Comment: @Mike : its 18.04 related & please do not use gloog spyshuts